# Loop through 3 different folders to get file contents and execute in db server

Tags: c#, tfs

I have 3 different folders in TFS : tables, scripts and objects. 
I Want to loop through three folders to get the file contents and execute them in the SQL server in the order tables, scripts and objects using C#. Want to make it configuration based.
Can anybody help me out with this?

Code:

```
class Program
{
    public void DownloadFiles()
    {
        string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "";
        string serverPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key2"];
        string localPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"];

        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
        VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        foreach (Item item in versionControlServer.GetItems(serverPath, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.Full, DeletedState.NonDeleted, ItemType.File, true).Items)
        {
            string target = Path.Combine(localPath, item.ServerItem.Substring(2));

            if (item.ItemType == ItemType.Folder && !Directory.Exists(target))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
                Console.WriteLine("Created the target folder");
            }
            else if (item.ItemType == ItemType.File)
            {
                item.DownloadFile(target);
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Downloaded files from TFS");
        ExecuteFiles();
    }
    public void ExecuteFiles()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn1"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"], "*.sql", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
                Console.WriteLine(file);
                Console.WriteLine(contents);

                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = contents;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
              }

        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        obj.DownloadFiles();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
<add key="key1" value="C:\downloads"/>
<add key="key2" value="$/App1/Application"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn1" connectionString="Data Source=Server_Name;Initial Catalog=db_Name;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: There are quite a few different ways you could do this. You could use TfGet.exe to download the files https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx. Another way would be to create a custom build which executes a batch file or powershell script to run the scripts. Whats happening with your current code? What version of TFS?